# Setting up castle windsor installers both in test and development environments

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, castle-windsor

In my MVC3/nhibernate web application, I have my windsor installers in my /Web project currently.

I want to setup both test and development environments the same, is it a good idea to push windsor configuration/installers to their own project then?

Answer (score 2):

Nope - not a good idea. Installers are a project specific bootstrap code and they should not be reused. Moreover you likely don't want to have *exactly* the same installers in both projects. Likely you want to fake out Facebook integration in test, use local database, disable caching etc.

Not worth having those headaches to save few lines of code. Reuse is overrated.